# How can I get var output data when my return type is IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to get data from `var result = new` not from `IEnumerable`. Please help me if is their any alternate solution, please let me know.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee_Join> GetEmployees(int paginate)    
{
    int FilterdCount = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = Db.Dbcontect)
    {
        var employee = new List<Employee_Join>();

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetEmployees_By_Pagination", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pagination", paginate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", 5);

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Employee_Join emp = new Employee_Join();

                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["EmployeeId"]))
                {
                    emp.Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
                }

                emp.EmpName = rdr["EmpName"].ToString();
                emp.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                emp.Cnt_Name = rdr["CountryName"].ToString();

                employee.Add(emp);
            }
        }

        var result = new
                    {
                        iTotalRecords = GetTotalEmployeeCount(),
                        iTotalDisplayRecords = FilterdCount,
                        aaData = employee
                    };

        return employee;
    }
}
```

I need `var result = new` output not employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `result`, you need to create a ViewModel / DTO class from it, since C# does not let your return anonymous objects from methods (technically you can, but this creates a lot of additional work down the road, so just don't, please).

```
public class MyCustomDTO
{
    public Type iTotalRecords { get; set; }
    public Type iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
    public Type employee { get; set; }
}
```

The change your code so it does not create an anonyomous type, but your new class:

```
var result = new MyCustomDTO
{
    iTotalRecords = GetTotalEmployeeCount(),
    iTotalDisplayRecords = FilterdCount,
    aaData = employee
};

return employee;
```

Finally change to return type of your function to reflect the correct type

```
public MyCustomDTO GetEmployees(int paginate)   { /* ... */}
```

Comment: It is rather likely that the first two `Type`s are `int`, and the last one certainly is `List<Employee_Join>`.